# Dask: Bokeh and progressbar very slow update

Tags: dask

I have had some issues with the visualization of the progress on my tasks.

I used to use the status page on the 8787 port, but visualizations don't always seem as smooth (refresh rates) as what I can see in blogposts.

I was quite happy when using the `dask.diagnostics.progress` since it ran smoothly and had a timer.

But this time when trying to persist a dataframe, my progress got blocked (stayed at 2.4 seconds and never advanced). Updating it doesn't fix the problem and on the 8787 I am not getting much info either. Any ideas why this happens?

[image]

Comment: I've improved the feedback of the progress bars here: https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The progress bar will stop if the computation has failed.  You might want to check that `users1` is producing a good result.  A simple way to do this would be to trigger a cheap computation on the full dataframe, like `len`

```
>>> len(users1)
Exception ...
```

Other reasons for non-responsive progress bars include a poor internet connection, or a very saturated scheduler (if there are millions of tasks), but neither of these seem to be the case in your situation.